# Defining async function inside promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I am writing code for promises using **.then**. Now, I have decided to write it using await/async. I have called a function **add_Lessons** inside promise and then call another **function** in **.then** of that function. Here is my code using **.then**.

```
function create_section(sections,course_ID,i) {
return new Promise(
    (resolve) => {
        var s_duration = 0;
        var sname = sections[i].name;
        var s_obj = {
            //some object;
        }
        var section_id;
        DB.section.create(s_obj,function (err, data_s) 
        {
            if (err) return next(err);
            section_id = data_s._id;
            var lesson = sections[i].lessons;
            add_lessons(lesson,section_id,i)
            .then(function(arr){
                resolve(arr);
            })
        });
    }
);
};
```

This is the code using **await/async**.

```
function create_section(sections,course_ID,i) {
return new Promise(
    async function resolve() {
        var s_duration = 0;
        var sname = sections[i].name;
        var s_obj = {
           //some obj
        }
        var section_id;
        DB.section.create(s_obj,function (err, data_s) 
        {
            if (err) return next(err);
            section_id = data_s._id;
            var lesson = sections[i].lessons;
            var arr = await add_lessons(lesson,section_id,i)
            resolve(arr);
        });
    }
);
};
```

The code using await/async shows an error that add_lessons is unexpected identifier.
So tell me how to define async function inside promise?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You put `async` in front of a wrong function. This function should be `async`:

```
DB.section.create(s_obj,function (err, data_s)
```

like this:

```
DB.section.create(s_obj, async function (err, data_s)
```

You can use `await` only inside of a function that has `async` keyword - not in all functions that are inside other functions that have `async` keyword.

But also what you should pass to a `new Promise()` constructor is a function that takes `resolve` as a parameter instead of a function that is itself named `resolve`. Instead of this:

```
return new Promise(
    async function resolve() {
```

you should use something like:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
```

and then also you probably should run `reject` instead of `next(error)` - so instead of:

```
if (err) return next(err);
```

you may try:

```
if (err) return reject(err);
```

if you actually want to reject the promise that is returned from the `create_section()` function.

You are mixing three ways of asynchronous control flow: callbacks, promises and async/await. You need to fully understand all of them to be able to combine them without problems.

I would recommend writing a wrappers that return promises for all of the functions that take callbacks, like this:

```
const sectionCreate = (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  DB.section.create(...args, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve data;
  });
});
```

(or you can use Bluebird's promisify for that)
and now you'll be able to use that in your async/await flow easily:

```
async function create_section(sections, course_ID, i) {
    var s_duration = 0;
    var sname = sections[i].name;
    var s_obj = {
       //some obj
    }
    var section_id;
    var data = await sectionCreate(s_obj);
    var section_id = data_s._id;
    var lesson = sections[i].lessons;
    var arr = await add_lessons(lesson, section_id, i);
    return arr;
}
```

This assumes that `add_lessons()` returns a promise which is implied but your code but it may not be the case. You can `await` on promises so you can use `await` in front of function calls that return promises.

Note that every `async` function returns a promise so you don't need to do it explicitly.

Comment: thank you for your help...can you please suggest me some good material to learn node.js...i know basics of node.js, thanks again...

Comment: @akashmodi I can recommend Node Tuts by Pedro Teixeira for a good start at http://nodetuts.com/ and I recommend CodeSchool: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/real-time-web-with-node-js and NodeSchool: https://nodeschool.io/ plus a lot of good tutorials and talks on YouTube. Good luck!

Comment: @akashmodi Also search for talks by Domenic Denicola about Promises.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getData = new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.co2m/todos/1");
      if (!response.ok) {
        return rej("Error while fetch");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      return res(data);
    } catch (error) {
      return rej(error);
    } 
});

getData
.then(data=>console.log(data))
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).